# Why the superexchange interaction is antiferromagnetically favorable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism, exchange-interaction

From Stephen Blundell's book 'Magnetism in Condensed Matter', the superexchange interaction between two magnetic ions mediated by non-magnetic ions is generally antiferromagnetic. In his book, he wrote (for the figure below), '***Superexchange in a magnetic oxide. The arrows show the spins of the four electrons and how they are distributed over the transition metal (M) and oxygen (O) atoms, M is assumed to have a single unpaired electron, making it magnetic. If the moments on the transition metal atoms arc coupled antiferrornagneticslly (a. b, c), the ground state is (a) and this can mix with excited configurations like (b) and (c). The magnetic electrons can thus be delocalizcd over the M-O-M unit, thus lowering the kinetic energy. If the moments on the metal (M) atoms are coupled ferromagnetically (d,e,f) the ground state (d) cannot mix with excited configurations like (c) and (f) because these configurations are prevented by the exclusion principle. The ferromagnetic configuration therefore costs more energy.***'

It seems that by having antiferromagnetic configuration one can have more delocalized electron distribution which decreases the kinetic energy. However it is very hard to understand based on the figure and above explanation. Could anyone please give me a more clearer explanation about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be understood by the degenerate perturbation theory.
First, we need to derive the effective Hamiltonian of the system.
In the system, there is a large onsite repulsion, which is given as,
$$
H_U = U (n_{1\uparrow}n_{1\downarrow} +n_{2\uparrow}n_{2\downarrow}),
$$
Here the subscribe $1$ and $2$ refer the two metal atoms.
Before deriving the effective hopping terms, we identify the groundstate of $H_U$. The ground state of $H_U$ are 4-fold degnerated, which are, $c_{1\uparrow}^\dagger c_{2\uparrow}^\dagger|0\rangle$, $c_{1\uparrow}^\dagger c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger|0\rangle$,$c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger c_{2\uparrow}^\dagger|0\rangle$, ,$c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger|0\rangle$ with $E_U=0$.
Since 4-fold ground states, we consider the degenerate perturbation theory.
We should consider the possible processes which can transform one groundstate to another, since such process will break the degenracy.
For example, we can formulate the process between state(a) to state(b) as, $ t^2 c_{O\downarrow}^\dagger c_{2\downarrow}c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger c_{O\downarrow} = t^2n_{O\downarrow} c_{2\downarrow}c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger$. This is nothing just a hopping between two atoms with amplitude $t^2n_{O\downarrow}$. Including all such hoppings between two atoms, we have,
$$
H_{t_1} = t_1 (\sum_\sigma c_{1\sigma}^\dagger c_{2\sigma} +h.c.).
$$
In the following, we will see that, up to second order perturbation, $H_{t_1}$ will break the groundstate degeneracy.
Before perturbation calculation, there are also another type of hoppings, like from state(a) to state(c), which we formulate as,
$$
H_{t_2} = t_2 (c_{1\sigma}^\dagger c_{2\bar{\sigma}}^\dagger +h.c.).
$$
It's impossible to perform the system from state(d) to (e) or (f). Such that, we have the effective Hamiltonian, $H= H_U + H_{t_1}+H_{t_2}$.
In the basis spanned by the four ground states, $H_U$ is 4x4 zero matrix.
Up to second order perturbation, $H_{t1}+H_{t_2}$ gives,
$$
-\frac{2t_1^2}{U} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0& -1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} - \frac{t_2^2}{2U}\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0& 1 & 1& 0\\
0& 0 &0 &0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By diagonalizing the above matrix, one can derive the eigen states
are, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (c_{1\uparrow}^\dagger c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger |0\rangle - c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger c_{2\uparrow}^\dagger |0\rangle),$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (c_{1\uparrow}^\dagger c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger |0\rangle + c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger c_{2\uparrow}^\dagger |0\rangle)$，$c_{1\uparrow}^\dagger c_{2\uparrow}^\dagger |0\rangle$，$c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger |0\rangle$ with energy, $-4t_1^2/U$, $-t_2^2/U$,$0$,$0$.
Since, $t_1\approx t_2$, the lowest energy state is the singlet state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (c_{1\uparrow}^\dagger c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger |0\rangle - c_{1\downarrow}^\dagger c_{2\uparrow}^\dagger |0\rangle)$.